# Why Flutter doesn't have ListView.iterable() constructor?

Tags: flutter, listview, widget

It's mostly for discussion, but really.

I haven't found anything similar on the internet, so I'm thinking maybe there's some performance hit or maybe no one haven't tried it. But if not, this constructor will be very helpful in reducing boilerplate code for `ListView`.

Commonly, in Flutter, when we use `ListView.builder()` constructor, it looks something like this:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final items = <ListItem>[
    // item 1,
    // item 2,
    // ... et cetera
  ];
  
  // ... code
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => SomeFancyListTile(
      leading: Image.network(items[index].imageUrl),
      title: Text(items[index].title),
    ),
    itemCount: items.length,
  ),
  // ... more code
}
```

Which is totally fine, but recently, I needed to use `LinkedList` to modify widget based on neighboring elements, which doesn't have convenient `[]` operator, but only have `.elementAt(index)` method. However, knowing how `LinkedList`s are structured, the code will be very unoptimized with large lists (rendering the whole list take O(n^2)).

But then I thought that it doesn't need to be that way as `ListView` renders items one after another, which is exactly how iterator works.

So, I implemented a custom `SliverChildDelegate`, which does exactly that - combines the functionality of iterator with `ListView`'s rendering. It also brought up a few syntactic improvements that reduces boilerplate code and the use of `items[index]` every time we need to access the list item.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

typedef ValueWidgetBuilder<T> = Widget Function(BuildContext context, T value);

class SliverIterableBuilderDelegate<T> extends SliverChildDelegate {
  SliverIterableBuilderDelegate(
    this.iterable, {
    required this.builder,
  }) : iterator = iterable.iterator;

  final Iterable<T> iterable;
  final ValueWidgetBuilder<T> builder;
  final Iterator<T> iterator;

  @override
  Widget? build(BuildContext context, int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= iterable.length) {
      return null;
    }

    if (iterator.moveNext()) {
      return builder(context, iterator.current);
    }

    return null;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverChildDelegate oldDelegate) => true;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final items = <ListItem>[
    // item 1,
    // item 2,
    // ... et cetera
  ];
  
  // ... code
  child: ListView.custom(
    childrenDelegate: SliverIterableBuilderDelegate(
      builder: (context, value) => SomeFancyListTile(
        leading: Image.network(value.imageUrl),
        title: Text(value.title),
      ),
  ),
  // ... more code
}
```

So, I was wondering whether this approach have some drawbacks? And also, a suggestion to add a `ListView.iterable()` constructor to reduce the code even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice idea, but this implementation does not work. You're calling `Iterator.moveNext()` regardless of the direction of scroll. If you have a long list, scroll down a lot, then scroll back up, you're going to start seeing the list continue in reverse. I've made an example to show this behavior, it can be directly copy-pasted into [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final items = List.generate(1000, (val) => val, growable: false);
  
  // ... code
  return ListView.custom(
    childrenDelegate: SliverIterableBuilderDelegate(
      items,
      builder: (context, value) => Text(
        value.toString()
      ),
  )
);}
}

typedef ValueWidgetBuilder<T> = Widget Function(BuildContext context, T value);

class SliverIterableBuilderDelegate<T> extends SliverChildDelegate {
  SliverIterableBuilderDelegate(
    this.iterable, {
    required this.builder,
  }) : iterator = iterable.iterator;

  final Iterable<T> iterable;
  final ValueWidgetBuilder<T> builder;
  final Iterator<T> iterator;

  @override
  Widget? build(BuildContext context, int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= iterable.length) {
      return null;
    }

    if (iterator.moveNext()) {
      return builder(context, iterator.current);
    }

    return null;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverChildDelegate oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Easiest solution is to just use a normal list instead of a linked one so that you can have fast indexing operations.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that. Do you think it is still possible to implement a solution that will take care of that use case?

Comment: @AnuarOtynshin I'm finding it difficult to see a way to do that since LinkedLists only have a function to iterate forwards. Maybe there's a way to do it with some lower level widgets or something like that? SliverChildDelegate definitely seems like it was made with indexed Lists in mind.